# Test click events on router-link of vuejs using jest

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs

```
<ul>
  <router-link to="/" tag="li" active-class="active" exact><a >Home</a></router-link>
  <router-link to="/contact" tag="li" exact><a>contact</a></router-link>
  <router-link to="/other" tag="li" exact><a>other</a></router-link>
<ul/>
```

Test.spec.js
(i am trying to trigger the click event and check the other component is loaded or not)

```
await wrapper.findAll('a').at(2).trigger('click')
await wrapper.vm.$nextTick()
expect(wrapper.contains('This is other Page')).toBe(true)
```

but the test is failing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to do test about router-link, the behavior of this you dont care, becouse; the behavior that you need is only know that the  is rendered. No more.
You can do test like this

```
 const wrapper: any = shallowMount(YourComponent, {
    stubs: ['router-link', 'router-view']
  });

expect(wrapper.html()).toContain('to="/contact"');
```

Other thing that you can doing is verify that the prop "to" recived exactly the string "/contact"

For me, is enough .toContain(...)

PD: sorry for my english.

Comment: Then how should i test after clicking the link the expected component is rendered or not ?

Comment: You are doing unit test, if you need to know if after to do click is rendered the other page, you need to do integration test. Remmber, with unit test just should test a single component.

Comment: Just for reference, on vue test utils ^2.2.10 now `stubs` is property from `options.global`

Comment: Also, your testing strategy is to test implementation, which I would avoid if possible, speaking of the prop. Is there any other way?